# sendmail не отправляет письма

Tags: php, sendmail

На сервере `ubuntu 16` стоит `sendmail` в качестве `MTA`

Он почти корректно работает.
Я отправляю письмо с помощью функции `mail()` из `php` файла. Оно абсолютно корректно отправляется и приходит на ящик.
Но если я пробую отправить письмо на тот же ящик через консоль
вот так

```
sendmail -f mysmtp@gmail.com -v myemail@yandex.ru
```

Оно не приходит на ящик получателя.
У меня gmail в качестве smtp. На нём это письмо попадает в отправленные сразу. Все с виду хорошо. Гугл говорит что отправил письмо.

Но оно так и не приходит даже в спам.
Подскажите куда копать?

Comment: Логи серверные покажите.

Answer (score 0):

Рекомендую использовать: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer. Решает множество проблем